# Is there a name for the variables in a regression equation that cause it to be overfit or near-overfit?

Tags: regression, terminology

I call these "tweaker" variables—the ones that pass some statistical test for inclusion, but whose contribution is minimal—but I'm looking for a better or established label.

Answer (score 0):

A collective term for the set would be "over-parameterization"